# React-admin sorting in list doesn't work as expected

Tags: list, react-admin

in my react-admin project I have a simple list. Unfortunately, when I click on the column headers, sorting doesn't work. The arrow animations appear and the URL get's updated, but the sorting don't get applied to the list. Why does this happen?

**List.tsx**

```
export const List = (props) => {
   return (
          <List {...props} bulkActionButtons={false}>
                 <Datagrid rowStyle={postRowStyle}>
                        <TextField source="number" sortBy="number" />
                        <TextField source="salutation" label="Salutation" sortBy="salutation" />
                        <TextField source="firstname" label="Firstname" sortBy="firstname" />
                        <TextField source="lastname" label="Lastname" sortBy="lastname" />
                        <EmailField source="email" label="Email" sortBy="email" />
                        <FunctionField render={record => `${record.street} ${record.housenumber}`} label="Street" sortBy="street"/>
                 </Datagrid>
          </List>
   );
}
```

**CustomDataProvider.ts**

```
const CustomDataProvider = (apiUrl, httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson): DataProvider => ({
 getList: (resource, params) => {
 const {page, perPage} = params.pagination;
 const {field, order} = params.sort;

 const query = {
   ...fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter),
   sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
   _start: (page - 1) * perPage,
   _end: page * perPage,
 };
 const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

 return httpClient(url).then(({headers, json}) => {
   if (!headers.has('x-total-count')) {
     throw new Error(
       '...'
     );
   }

   return {
     data: json.map(function (data) {
       return {...data, id: data.nummer}
     }),
     total: parseInt(
       headers.get('x-total-count').split('/').pop(),
       10
     ),
   };
 });
},
```

Comment: In react-admin, records are sorted on the server, look at its response, does the order of records change?

Comment: Ah no, the order of the records didn't change. I guess, I need to take a look at the backend then.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the sortBy if it's the same as source